# Change constraint in FluentLayout

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, cirrious.fluentlayout

I am using FluentLayout to create IOS layouts and I am trying to remove a constraint and it does not work. I tried using both RemoveConstraint and Constraint.Active = false but none of them are working. 
Do you have any idea on how can I do this?

Comment: Did you reload the view after change the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You should call LayoutIfNeeded() on the current View afterward.